# Regexp. Select second value from list

Tags: regex, logging, zabbix, domaincontroller

I create trigger in Zabbix -

```
"Event Log - User Account Changed ({{ITEM.VALUE}.iregsub("Account Name:\s*([\w- ]*)", "\1")} change {{ITEM.VALUE}.iregsub("Account Name:\s*([\w- ]*)", "\1")})"
```

I get:

```
"Event Log - User Account Changed (Admin_Name change Admin_Name)",
```

But i want to get:

```
"Event Log - User Account Changed (Admin_Name change User_Name)"
```

I want to select the second value from the list. I can not understand how to do this?

Help, please.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I do not know how much this is correct, but it works ...

```
Target Account:\s+.+\s+Account Name:\s*([\w- ]*)
```

As a result, the name of the triger looks like this:

```
Event Log - User Account Changed (DOMAIN\{{ITEM.VALUE}.iregsub("Account Name:\s*([\w- ]*)", "\1")} change DOMAIN\{{ITEM.VALUE}.iregsub("Target Account:\s+.+\s+Account Name:\s*([\w- ]*)", "\1")})
```

My problem is solved. Thanks to all! )